# Create indicator variables in SPSS using loops

Tags: loops, variables, syntax, spss

I am trying to create some indicator variables in SPSS using a loop.

I want to create 17 new variables ABA(1-17) that take a value of 1 if BA(1-17) equals 1. I was trying something like:

```
VECTOR ABA(17).
LOOP #i = 1 to 17.
IF(BA(#i)=1) ABA(#i) = 1.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

This, unfortunately, just creates variables with missing values. Does the above code just need a small tweak or is their a more efficient way to accomplish creating the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to define the set of `BA` variables as a vectors before you can reference them as such in the code. So try:

```
VECTOR ABA(17) /BA=BA1 to BA17.
LOOP #i = 1 to 17.
IF(BA(#i)=1) ABA(#i) = 1.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Note, given the `BA` variables already exist in the dataset you cannot reference them as `VECTOR BA(17).` but instead must use `VECTOR BA=BA1 to BA17.` If they are not in order in the datafile then you will have to get them in order using `ADD FILES FILE` to re-arrange variable ordering.

Comment: You are correct! I actually did try 'VECTOR BA(17)' and it did not work.

Comment: I don't know why `SPSS` doesn't allow just that but it bugs me also, especially so when variables are not in order. If they are not, I tend to jump to python for a solution...which is much better at handling these types of dynamics.

Comment: @JinneshSutar do you know of any good online resources that explain how to create loops and vectors in SPSS?

Comment: The Programming and Data Management book is great resource: https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2015/04/Programming-and-Data-Management-for-IBM-SPSS-Statistics-23.pdf

Comment: You actually don't need to loop here. `RECODE ABA1 TO ABA17 (1 = 1)(ELSE = SYSMIS) INTO BA1 TO BA17.` would produce equivalent results.

Comment: @AndyW agreed! Would opt for that approach myself also. Likely much more efficient too and syntax much easier to read.

Comment: As a general matter, when you need to use a long list of  noncontiguous variables, the STATS SELECT VARIABLES (Utilities > Define Variable Macro) extension command can often help.  It defines a macro listing variables selected by metadata such as a pattern in the names.  In this case, it might be something like SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!BA" 
/PROPERTIES PATTERN = "BA".  That macro could be used anywhere that a variablel list is acacepted.  Other properties such as type can also be specified.